# How to fix traceroute on MacOS just shows asterisks?

Tags: mac, network

I am trying to use the `traceroute` command on MacOS 12.6 to get a trace route. But no matter what arguments I am using, I am getting the same output every time, a list consisting only of asterisks:

```
traceroute -n -P udp  -p 22 google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.168.14), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
31  * * *
32  * * *
33  * * *
34  * * *
35  * * *
36  * * *
37  * * *
38  * * *
39  * * *
40  * * *
41  * * *
42  * * *
43  * * *
44  * * *
45  * * *
46  * * *
47  * * *
48  * * *
49  * * *
50  * * *
51  * * *
52  * * *
53  * * *
54  * * *
55  * * *
56  * * *
57  * * *
58  * * *
59  * * *
60  * * *
61  * * *
62  * * *
63  * * *
64  * * *
```

Other arguments I played around:

```
-r
-p port
-P tcp|udp|icmp
-a
-n
```

What else can I try to get some meaningful output?

Comment: That's not something you "fix".  Your traceroute is not receiving responses, which is what the display indicates.  What problem are you trying to solve that you need to send UDP probes on port 22 to a Google IP?

Comment: This isn’t likely a macOS or traceroute issue. Far more likely a router or isp configuration issue. Is traceroute the only problem noticed?

Comment: I want to get the traceroute, so I can trace a route when I connect to some random page. Other than all the *** I see no other issues. But I would like to see where the trace is going.

Comment: @Alex Ok, if that's the case, what's the need for UDP instead of ICMP, and the probes of port 22?  A normal ICMP traceroute to various Google IP's works fine.

Comment: How to do a "normal" ICMP traceroute to google? What parameters/arguments to use?

Answer (score 1):

Using `traceroute` without any special parameters should work fine:

```
$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.203.110), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  SUPPRESSED (192.168.1.1)  4.001 ms  3.973 ms  3.962 ms
 2  SUPPRESSED (212.51.N.N)  4.620 ms  4.610 ms  4.354 ms
 3  r1.790hot.fiber7.init7.net (141.195.82.218)  4.590 ms  4.779 ms  4.769 ms
 4  r1zrh13.core.init7.net (141.195.81.42)  5.214 ms r1glb1.core.init7.net (141.195.80.28)  5.289 ms r1zrh13.core.init7.net (141.195.81.42)  5.460 ms
 5  r1glb1.core.init7.net (141.195.80.28)  5.490 ms r1glb3.core.init7.net (5.180.135.155)  5.441 ms  5.165 ms
 6  r1glb3.core.init7.net (5.180.135.155)  5.664 ms r1glb1.core.init7.net (5.180.135.136)  2.653 ms  3.057 ms
 7  pni-google.init7.net (77.109.135.214)  2.183 ms  3.625 ms r1glb1.core.init7.net (5.180.135.136)  4.521 ms
 8  pni-google.init7.net (77.109.135.214)  3.610 ms * *
 9  zrh04s16-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.203.110)  4.107 ms  3.960 ms *
```

Comment: I had the asterisks at the employer previous to the current and it was intentional from the network team - they implemented a Layer 2 & Layer 3 switching and routing strategy with multiple VLAN IIRC which made tools like `mtr` and `traceroute`  ineffective at their intended job - I'll put up a longer answer

Comment: @bmike In such cases, there is nothing to be done user-side. But the question is rather vague on this (and it has been a while since it got asked), so we don't actually know the issues the OP was facing.

Comment: Agreed - and I'm not really super keen on all the layers +1 for sure on your answer that the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious fix is to not change your Mac. Instead take it to a different network that only uses layer 3 switching and routing.

It's reporting back typical results when it's connected to the [internet via a Layer 2 switch](https://serverfault.com/q/457796/81174). Most home networks and smaller ones switch on Layer 3 and provide the [traceroute results without any asterisks and showing each and every hop like @nohillside provided](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/468141/5472).

- https://www.auvik.com/franklyit/blog/layer-3-switches-layer-2/
- https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-121-mainline/12778-ping-traceroute.html

I don't think there's a tool to get a Layer 3 switch to tell you hops, but maybe someone more experienced in networking can point out the tool or option.

In my experience, the asterisks get placed due to a retry and on a timer by the code between probes it sends (and the TTL) and not that it indicates a response from a specific network gear in a trace.

I would ask what you're trying to do with traceroute and to check with the network to ask about VLAN and Layer 2 / Layer 3 switching to get at why your route is filled with asterisks. It's not likely a problem with your Mac or your usage.

If none of that works, perhaps you have a firewall and need to try the evasion mode (well it can't hurt to try):

```
traceroute -e google.com
```

> -e      Firewall evasion mode.
> Use fixed destination ports for UDP and TCP probes.  The destination port does NOT increment with each packet sent.

Answer (score -1):

I found that traceroute -I gave me more complete results.

```
-I, --icmp
  Use ICMP ECHO for probes
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229301/585893)

Comment: How does your post exactly answer the question? Pls provide more details to support your answer.

Comment: Isn't that the same as -P icmp? Your answer is asking for a synonym of what the OP already said didn't work. Perhaps you could edit this to explain more?